# how to fix missmatch database compatability levels

Tags: asp.net, azure

here is the question: I'm trying to publish ASP.Net project on Azure. Half way there, i have verified connection to Azure and now i just need to attach database. But when i publish it - it gives strange error:

```
Error   1   Web deployment task failed. (The database compatibility level '12' is not within the supported range of 80 to 130.)     0   0
```

Before that i had a problem with connection string password and login, but after creating a new web app it sorted. Now this.
Any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level

Comment: Yes i seen this link. My db is level 12, target - 140. But i didnt get how to fix it...

Comment: What version of SQL Server is your db created with?

Comment: i figured the syntax to change comatbility ALTER DATABASE phclub  
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140;  
GO but that didnt fix an error anyway

Comment: product version is 12.0.2000.8

Comment: Actually it did work. THanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out, I thought I knew from that article but it wasn't clear for sure.  You should post your own answer so someone else can find it.

Answer (score 2):

Please connect to the SQL Azure server using SQL Server Management Studio and run the following statement:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyFirstDb SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL =  130;
```

You can find a list of the compatibility level [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017)